# How to check if a Canvas is empty?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

Is there a way to check if a Tkinter canvas has items or is empty?

I tried something like

```
prints self.canvas.winfo_children()
```

but it always prints an empty list, items or no items.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `self.canvas.find_all()` and check if it returns an empty tuple.